# Microsoft.LiveSDK Not Signed Using an Apple Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode5.1

I am trying to update my app using xcode 5.1.1. and the new iTunesConenct. I was able to submit it successfully before the new changes to iTuens Conenct but now I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle 'Microsoft.LiveSDK' at bundle
path 'Payload/..../LiveSDK.framework' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate"
```

I was able to successfully upload the previous versions of the same code but after the recent changes to iTuens Connect, I am getting this error.

Anyone has any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the LiveSDK framework from copy bundles step.  Then add the resources (everything but the private headers directory) to your project.  i.e. right click add to project.

The problem is the whole framework is being included in your .app